# Date loses position when translating from Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, date

My problem is that when I display my SQL table, the date is in a different order as it is on the SQL table, so the date does not correspond with the eid.

The SQL table has the following order.

> EID 72:  DATE: 2014-04-08 SUBJECT: 3rd event
>
> EID 70:  DATE: 2014-04-02 SUBJECT: 1st one
>
> EID 69:  DATE: 2014-04-01 SUBJECT: 2nd Event
>
> EID 71:  DATE: 2014-03-31 SUBJECT: Fourth event

However it displays in html as

> EID: 71 DATE: 2014-04-08 SUBJECT: 3rd event
>
> EID: 72 DATE: 2014-04-01 SUBJECT: Fourth event
>
> EID: 69 DATE: 2014-04-02 SUBJECT: 1st one
>
> EID: 70 DATE: 2014-03-31 SUBJECT: 2nd Event

For some reason when translating from SQL through PHP, the date loses it's order. Here is my php code which displays the results

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","password") or die ("could not connect to the server");
        mysql_select_db("app") or die ("that database could not be found");

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `notification` WHERE `date` AND `active`=0 < NOW()") or die ("The query could not be completed. Please try again later");

        while($noticerow=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            $nid[] = $noticerow['nid'];
            $eid[] = $noticerow['eid'];
            $subject[] = $noticerow['subject'];
            $noticedate[] = $noticerow['date'];
        }
        
        $a=0;
        while(mysql_num_rows($result)>$a)
        {
            echo "<tr><td><a onclick='location.href=\"calendar.php?action=display_event&oid=".$eid[$a]."\"'>".$eid[$a]."</a></td><td><a onclick='location.href=\"calendar.php?action=display_event&oid=".$eid[$a]."\"'>".$noticedate[$a]."</a></td><td><a onclick='location.href=\"calendar.php?action=display_event&oid=".$eid[$a]."\"'>".$subject[$a]."</a></td><td><form action='rnotice.php' method='POST'><button value='submit' class='btn btn-danger pull-right' type='submit' onclick='location.href=\"calendar.php?action=display_event&oid=".$eid[$a]."\"'>Remove</button><input name='eid' type='hidden' value=".$eid[$a]."></form></td></tr>";
        $a++;
        }
```

Comment: Already tried it, doesn't fix the positioning issue. The date still doesn't match the eid and subject

Comment: Why do you have 2 loops to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the order by keyword in the SQL statement but I don't know the columns name you are using.

Assuming that you want to order them by EID and you have a column name called EID for that your select statement should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM  `notification` WHERE `date` AND `active`=0 < NOW() order by eid ASC
```

if you want to sort it by date then

```
SELECT * FROM  `notification` WHERE `date` AND `active`=0 < NOW() order by `date` ASC
```

To sort the records in a descending order, you can use the DESC keyword instead of ASC

Comment: I tried that, it just changed the positioning of the items but the dates still did not match the eid or subject

Comment: Yes, I have not noticed that the data is not identical, so I thought all you need is sorting. How did you move it from MS-SQL to MySQL? what is/are the primary key(s)? did you let mysql generate them for you or did you enter them manually?

Comment: I have another field called $nid which is the primary key. Ahh ordering by this worked! Thank you